# Aframe Directly updating properties of aframe-particle-system-component in real time without setAttribute()

Tags: aframe, webvr

I'm using the [aframe-particle-system-component](https://github.com/IdeaSpaceVR/aframe-particle-system-component), and was using `.setAttribute()` on the `tick()` function to update the particle system in real time, but it performed terribly, leading to almost instant memory-related crashes. Is there a way to directly access the `maxAge`, `opacity`, and `enabled` properties of the system? I'm assuming this is the best way to tackle this as the framework advises that `.object3D` is directly accessed for performance reasons. I would like to be able to access the particle system in a similar manner. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

tldr: [here's](https://aframeparticlecontroller.glitch.me/) an example with animated opacity, size, and some toggles. Switching max age seems to wait until all current particles are gone, though no word about it in the [docs](https://squarefeet.github.io/ShaderParticleEngine/docs/api/global.html#EmitterOptions).

## 1. Gutting the particle system

The particle system is based on the [ShaderParticleEngine](https://github.com/squarefeet/ShaderParticleEngine/blob/master/docs/SPE.Emitter.md), so modyfing it won't be that THREE.js'ish.

From what I can tell, the `particle-system` creates and stores `SPE.Emitter`'s. You can access them here:

```
let particleSystem = this.el.component['particle-system']
let emitterGroup = particleSystem.particleGroup.emitters
```

Changing values - for example, if you have one emitter:

```
emitterGroup[0].disable()           // disables the emitter
emitterGroup[0].opacity.value = 0.1 // sets the opacity
```

## 2. A job for a-frame custom components

I'd create a custom component - which will upon any change iterate through the emitter group and change the attributes:

```
AFRAME.registerComponent('particle-controller', {
   schema: {
      opacity: {default: 1}
   },
   init: function() {
      let system = this.el.components['particle-system']
      this.emitterGroup = system.particleGroup.emitters
   },
   update: function() {
      this.setValueInEmitters(this.emitterGroup, 'opacity', this.data.opacity)
   },
   // may come in handy when changing more key-value pairs
   setValueInEmitters(group, prop, value) {
     for (let i = 0; i < group.length; i++) {
        group[i].prop.value = value
     }
   }
})
```

The schema could be fed with key-value pairs or such to make the component more universal.

## 3. Why setAttribute is so heavy

Gathering from the [source code](https://github.com/IdeaSpaceVR/aframe-particle-system-component/blob/master/dist/aframe-particle-system-component.js#L241), any change removes the old particle group and creates a new one from scratch.